# Are there any elf like creatures in non-European folklore?

Tags: mythical-creatures, folklore

I know that the elves didn't survive the transatlantic crossing but are there any stories of elves or similar creatures in other world mythologies?

Comment: Related: [What are the life-spans for faeries?](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/2905)

Comment: http://www.godchecker.com/pantheon/oceanic-mythology.php?deity=MATAGAIGAI  found this.

Answer (score 7):

There really aren't any that I can find. Elf-like creatures are pretty stricly Germanic, however there is the duende.

> A duende is a fairy- or goblin-like mythological creature from Iberian, South American, Chamorro and Filipino folklore

Duendes aren't really elves, they have more similarities to dwarves, but the mythological elves are very different from the ones you find in most fantasy books. Those are a creation mostly of J.R.R Tolkien, however, they were influenced by Germanic culture.

You can read about the duende here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duende_(mythology)

And learn about mythological elves here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elf

Comment: I just tried putting duende into Google Translate and it came out as elf with dwarf as an alternate translation. So there you go.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJPe6hL7M0U
(An elder of the Crow tribe tells a story about Little People)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7d5KGV_HcY
An author who lived among the Cherokee tribe, who studied their culture and legends, is featured on a News program for her claim that the Little People actually existed long ago. In other words, she believes the legends are based in fact.

The Cherokee and Crow tribes, and (so I've heard) many other NA tribes of North America, had persistent legends of "Little People".

https://www.gutenberg.org/files/45634/45634-h/45634-h.htm

James Mooney's "Myths of the Cherokee" (1902) makes 28 references of Little People, in a number of different legends.

If I remember correctly, Cherokee children were routinely warned not to venture out alone at night, for fear that they would be captured by the Little People. I personally haven't studied the legends that closely, although now I'm more curious.